# "Tagli di spesa", "tagli della spesa", "tagli alla spesa" oppure "tagli sulla spesa"?

Tags: difference, prepositions, phrase-choice

La crisi economica in molti paesi di Europa mette espressioni come queste all'ordine del giorno. Ho letto tutte queste espressioni, ma non riesco a capire quando si debba usare l'una o l'altra. Potreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

Ad esempio, cosa dovrei dire:

- "i tagli *di* spesa nell'ambito sanitario",
- "i tagli *della* spesa nell'ambito sanitario",
- "i tagli *alla* spesa nell'ambito sanitario"

oppure

- "i tagli *sulla* spesa nell'ambito sanitario"?

Comment: Un'idea puramente statistica la dà il solito Ngram Viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tagli+di+spesa%2Ctagli+della+spesa%2Ctagli+alla+spesa%2Ctagli+sulla+spesa&year_start=1960&year_end=2014&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctagli%20di%20spesa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctagli%20della%20spesa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctagli%20alla%20spesa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctagli%20sulla%20spesa%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"tagli di spesa"* è un'espressione generica, generale, versatile di carattere tecnico: *"...tagli di spesa o maggiori entrate/imposte"*

*"tagli della spesa"* sottindende, ed è spesso seguita, da 'pubblica'

*"tagli alla spesa"* è la più usata, l'ultima è poco accettabile.

Forse può essere d'interesse sapere che questa accezione di 'taglio' è nuova (ancora non registrata dalla Treccani, mi pare) e viene dall'inglese "spending **cuts** /review" che significa "riduzione". Propriamente 'taglio' in senso figurato indica una brusca chiusura: "*dare un taglio a...lla conversazione"*, o una soppressione: "*il taglio di una scena scabrosa"*. Il termine inglese spiega anche l'uso preponderante del plurale.

Comment: Scusa la pignoleria, bobie, ma a maggior ragione visto che siamo in un sito sulla lingua italiana potresti far caso all'accento giusto su “è”? Grazie!